Prevent web Updates in PWA?
I'm currently developing a PWA that will be published in the Microsoft Store. It basically works like an offline app, so all processing is done locally. My question is: Is it possible for a PWA to update exclusively through the Microsoft Store and not from any web URL? My concern is that if someone acquires the domain, they could potentially make a malicious update that users might download. Forcing cache could be managed by the service worker, but pressing Ctrl + F5 would still bypass the service worker and fetch data from the web.

Domainname ownership is such a critical component of security on the web, I feel all your focus should be on retaining the domain. Almost everything related to proving something is authentic hinges on domainnames. Are you worried you may not be able to afford renewing it in the future?

I'm worried that nobody will renew the domain name when I leave. Maybe I'm using the wrong tool for the job and should consider making it an Electron app instead.
